# button image is not working

Tags: css

I have an image attached to my code that is not shown in the IE:

```
#upload_button{
background-image:url(images/upload.gif);
width:215px;
height:61px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border:none;
}
```

Comment: which element does `#upload_button` refers here?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property "background-image" is not supported by IE7 and IE8.

You'll need to replace it with

"background:transparent url();"

Comment: Also, no-repeat should be added to that.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is perfectly working in IE 6/7/8.

```
#upload_button{
background-image:url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/41d7639adf8a1916fab202db8cb16273?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
width:215px;
height:61px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border:none;

}

  <input type="button" value="button" id="upload_button" />
```

Comment: suggest you to check the image location and add the relative URL properly.